# nbm-maven-plugin:build-installers bundled jvm - NetBeans Platform installing with bundled JVM

Tags: java, windows-installer, netbeans-platform

I have a NetBeans Platform application (8.0.2 if it matters) with bundled JVM and Installers (Windows only) generated using maven, specifically nbm-maven-plugin:build-installers. It has quite a bit of customization, but effectively it has jre.zip in it, which is extracted into jre folder as part of the installation and then used by the application as embedded java, by virtue of having jdkhome="./jre" in its conf file. Everything works as expected, but when you run installer itself it does require java to be present on the host, if it's not there you see "JDK 7 is required for installing ... Make sure that the JDK is properly  installed ...".

I've found all the discussions around it referencing each other, e.g. https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/installing_the_jre_via_an but they're all using ant and not maven. The ones talking about maven don't have much useful information. What am I missing? I'm sure it's simple enough, but I can't find an answer anywhere (. I'm sure I'm not the first one to hit this, help me please! Which , .conf parameters, template.xml sections are required? I already have jre both as zip and as self extracting exe as suggested in the blog above, but have no idea how to make it work.

Thank you very much for any ideas.